# Generate Excel file using Java and Jasper

Tags: java, excel, jsf, jasper-reports

I am not sure what the Problem is, but I am generating an excel file using Java and Jasper Correctly, I want to Instantly download the file to client site in xlsx format but the file is downloading with .xhtml extension. What do I need to do? I am using JSF.

Here is My method:

```
public void generateOutStandingDCReportXLS() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = db.getDbConnection();
            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            InputStream logourl = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/bi/jrxml/simba_logo.jpg");
            InputStream stainurl = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/bi/jrxml/coffee_stain.png");
            parameters.put("logo", logourl);
            parameters.put("stain", stainurl);
            InputStream url = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/bi/jrxml/Outstanding_DC.jrxml");
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(url);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
            ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
            String path = (String) ctx.getAttribute("reportdir");
            File f = new File(path);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
            }
            String reportDestination = f.getAbsolutePath() + "/OutStanding_DC_Report" + ".xlsx";  //This is generated Correctly
            File xlsFile = new File(reportDestination);
            JRXlsxExporter Xlsxexporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
            Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, xlsFile);
            Xlsxexporter.exportReport();//File is generated Correctly
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(reportDestination));
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            IOUtils.copy(fis, response.getOutputStream());
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "OutStanding_DC_Report" + ".xlsx"); //This is downloaded as .xhtml
            response.flushBuffer();
            fis.close();

        } catch (JRException asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException asd) {
                System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

The file on the server side is with the correct extension but the file getting downloaded has a .xhtml extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `setContentType()` and `setHeader()` before `IOUtils.copy()`.

Once you call `response.getOutputStream()` the headers are sent.

Comment: This is Still getting the file downloaded as .xhtml :(

Comment: @Stanley call `setContentType()` and `setHeader()` before `IOUtils.copy()`. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Wow that did work it out. Please Modify your answer so I can accept.

Answer (score -2):

Stanley, are you still facing the same issue?? if yes try to set below string in

```
response.setContentType() 

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

i.e.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Instead of

```
application/vnd.ms-excel i.e. response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

hope this will help.